# Linq SQL EF Core subselect always requests ALL columns for tables in subquery from database

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, subquery, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 with EF Core Web API running in front of a SQL Server. Front end is Angular.

There is a function where someone is able to select the campaigns that are running for multiple selected clients.

The models involved are:

```
public partial class Campaign
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int AdvertiserId { get; set; }
    public int SalesHouseId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string SearchCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CompanyURL { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnHold { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OnHoldSince { get; set; }
    public string OnHoldBy { get; set; }
    public .... more fields { get; set; }
}
```

I use the following LinqSql to pull the campaigns for the selected clients (example):

```
List<int> selectedClients = new List<int>() { 10414, 19529, 14025 };

var cams = (from cam in _dbContext.Campaigns
            join cl in (from cus in _dbContext.Customers.Where(cus => 
                        selectedClients.Contains(cus.CustomerId))
                        select new { cus.CustomerId, cus.CompanyName })
                        on cam.AdvertiserId equals cl.CustomerId
            select new { cam.CampaignId, cam.Description, cam.StartDate, cl.CompanyName})
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
```

The result returned is good and all works fine.

BUT I checked the SQL that is send down to the server and noticed that for the sub query ALL columns are requested:

```
SELECT [c].[CampaignId], [c].[Description], [c].[StartDate], [t].[CompanyName]
FROM [Campaigns] AS [c]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [c0].[CustomerId], [c0].[ACEndDate], [c0].[ACStartDate], [c0].[ActiveSince], [c0].[AgencyCommission], [c0].[Balance], [c0].[BalanceDate], [c0].[BankAccount], [c0].[CompanyName], [c0].[CompanyURL], [c0].[CreditLimit], [c0].[DebtorNumber], [c0].[Email], [c0].[EmailInvoice], [c0].[EmailOrderConfirmation], [c0].[FaxNumber], [c0].[FinanciallyResponsibleCustId], [c0].[InactiveSince], [c0].[InvDueDays], [c0].[InvFreqMargin], [c0].[InvoiceFrequency], [c0].[InvoiceInfo], [c0].[IsActive], [c0].[IsAdvertiser], [c0].[IsAdvertisingAgency], [c0].[IsAgency], [c0].[IsApprovedAgency], [c0].[IsDirectAdvertiser], [c0].[IsFinanciallyResponsible], [c0].[IsHolding], [c0].[IsOnHold], [c0].[IsOther], [c0].[IsProductionCompany], [c0].[IsTaxable], [c0].[OnHoldBy], [c0].[OnHoldReason], [c0].[OnHoldSince], [c0].[PaymentMethod], [c0].[PhoneNumber1], [c0].[PhoneNumber2], [c0].[PrintOrderConfirmation], [c0].[PrintZeroInvoices], [c0].[SearchCode], [c0].[SetInactiveBy], [c0].[VATId], [c0].[VATNumber]
    FROM [Customers] AS [c0]
    WHERE [c0].[CustomerId] IN (10414, 19529, 14025)
) AS [t] ON [c].[AdvertiserId] = [t].[CustomerId]
```

ALL columns from the table in the subquery are send back to the API. I only need the [*customerId*] and [*companyName*] fields.

I tried to use a DTO instead of the anonymous select in the subquery but that does not help either.

If the subselect consists of more tables, all columns of all tables in that sub select will be requested from the database.

Does anyone have an idea how to limit the columns from the sub-select here?

Comment: *"ALL columns from the table in the subquery are send back to the API"* Negative, only the columns from the final top level `SELECT` (in this case, `SELECT [c].[CampaignId], [c].[Description], [c].[StartDate], [t].[CompanyName]`) are send back to the client. in SQL, `TableA JOIN TableB` is equivalent of `(select * from TableA) JOIN (select * from TableB)`, but that doesn't mean all the columns from TableA and TableB are actually retrieved.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I changed my question into: Does anyone have an idea how to limit the columns from the sub-select here?
If I would write that SQL in a stored procedure I would just use the columns I would need in the sub-select.
I wonder if it would be possible to achieve that with EF core.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it is not needed EF Core limitation. Live with that or create issue in EF Core repository.